# Kubernetes - nfs: access denied by server while mounting - MacOS

Tags: macos, kubernetes, nfs

Unable to mount a pod - nfs: access denied by server while mounting

I have NFS Manager for Mac and i have tried removing all of the security. Right click on finder and connect to server and it works as it should. I can also see it in `showmount -e`

The error message in full;

`MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "magento2-monolith-volume" : mount failed: exit status 32 Mounting command: systemd-run Mounting arguments: --description=Kubernetes transient mount for /var/lib/kubelet/pods/cd5fb5f0-885a-11e9-9fb4-080027390119/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/magento2-monolith-volume
--scope -- mount -t nfs 192.168.31.135:/Users/macmini/desktop/magento2-devbox /var/lib/kubelet/pods/cd5fb5f0-885a-11e9-9fb4-080027390119/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/magento2-monolith-volume Output: Running scope as unit: run-r256a12ba3ca8416c904902f477ec2397.scope mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting
192.168.31.135:/Users/macmini/desktop/magento2-devbox`

Is there something that I am missing on MacOS? Most of the issues seem to be with people running on Linux. Is there anything specific to Mac and Kubernetes?

Comment: Maybe https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/#file-sharing

Comment: @spender ahhhh more steps.  Great thank you. I will go through that.  Appreciate the link

Comment: @spender Unfortunately it looks like I had configured everything correctly unfortunately.